# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. avcapturedeviceinput

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for :.video, position: .front)
    var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 10.2, *){

            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            do{
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
                captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
                captureSession?.addInput(input)
                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
                videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
                captureSession?.startRunning()
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func ImageCapture(_ sender: Any) {

    }
```

I am coding a simple camera app on swift code. I tried in 2 different ways but I get the same error in both.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

here

> `let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)`

How could I fix it?

Comment: are you running it in simulator? Coz it wont work. It will work in real device. Also safely unwrap your captureDevice using if let statement

Comment: oh I see. i wont work with simulator.

Comment: Did you add NSCameraUsageDescription in plist and used requestAccess(for:completionHandler:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running it in the simulator? Coz it won't work. It will work in a real device. Also safely unwrap your captureDevice using if let statement. This wont crash the app.

```
if #available(iOS 10.2, *){

    if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
        do{
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
            captureSession?.addInput(input)
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            captureSession?.startRunning()
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    } else {
        print("camera not available")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here [Optional Binding](https://medium.com/whoknows-swift/swift-what-is-the-optional-binding-7624c7f9098e) would help you out, it wraps the value if surely not nil and proceed the flow of program with confirmed wrapped value. Below is an an example of `Optional Binding in Swift`

```
if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
    // do you desired code here, here captureDevice object has a confirmed value 
}else{
    // here captureDevice is nil, can assist the user accordingly
}
```